# Pass the class name/method name in argument, possible?

Tags: c#, logging

I've made a method that logs an exception into a folder called Logs and save it in the text file. The format of the text output is like so:

```
Main thread has thrown an exception @ ClassName::MethodName : Exception.ToString();
```

`ClassName::MethodName` is a text that should contain which class and which method throws it (while doing the task). How is it possible to pass those arguments? For example, if I have a class named "Test", and I have this method:

```
public void DoSomething() {
    try {
        this.Name = "Test";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MainForm.Instance.LogException(e);
    }
```

Then if an exception was thrown, the arguments `Test::DoSomething` will be passed and shown. How is it possible to do it in C#?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Reflection`..

```
public void DoSomething() {
    try {
        this.Name = "Test";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        var method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        var methodName = method.Name;
        var className = method.ReflectedType.Name;
        MainForm.Instance.LogException(String.Format("{0} - {1}:{2}", className, methodName, e));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception has a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which gives you as much information as possible as to where the exception was thrown.

Comment: How can I take the class/method name from the StackTrace property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below:

```
 public static void DoSomething()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

                StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);

                Console.WriteLine("Class Name: {0}, Method Name: {1}", stackFrame.GetMethod().Module, stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.StackTrace.GetFrame(0)` will give you the most recent `StackFrame`.

Given that, `e.StackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod()` will give you an instance of `MethodBase`, from this instance, you can get the method name and class